# Repair an old cylindrical hinge on an old bedroom closet

Tags: repair, wood, hinges, closet

After moving day, I think the hinge of an old bedroom closet door became crooked (upper left photo). It's a metal bar that's screwed on the bottom of the door, and a small cylinder sticks out.

This cylinder is then placed in a metal bar on the floor of the closet (lower left photo), which has a hole to fit the cylinder. The door is only kept in place by one hinge at the bottom, and one at the top (connected to the roof of the closet).

I can't find a replace hinge, every hinge I find online seems to connect an XY plane with a XY plane, while this connects a XY plane with a ZX plane.

I suppose I could fix it by:

- replacing this hinge (but where to find one?)
- bend the metal bar back to a straight horizontal bar?
- implement another hinge system. This seems hard because the hinge has a slight offset from the edge of the door by 10cm/4" (right picture)
- other suggestions

[image: picture of door]

Update: I've found the Dutch name: '[speun](https://www.brico.be/nl/gereedschap-installatie/ijzerwaren/meubelbeslag/vynex-speun-staal-70-mm/5473551)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing I would try is to remove the old hinge components and straightening them carefully.  I would clean them and file off any burs to prevent future wear.

I think the stability of the wood around the hardware is just as important as the hardware itself and therefore, I would dedicate some time to ensuring the hinges go back properly.  I would sure up any soft, rotted, or splintered wood with glue.  I would cut some wood shims to put in the old screw holes.  I would use glue and perhaps get some new, slightly longer stainless screws.

Patients and craftsmanship will be the key to repairing this.

Comment: I'll try and straighten straighten the old hinge component.  Do you think you can still buy this somewhere? Just in case

Comment: I don't know where you would buy one of these, though I would think they are out there somewhere.  However, worst comes to worst, I think you could replicate it with some common bar stock, a drill, a vice, a hack saw and a file.